# The speed of port scan using nmap -sS and nmap -sT?

Tags: linux, network-programming, nmap, port-scanning

I am using nmap to do port scan for an experiment. The destination IP is 192.168.199.201. And I try the two commands below:

Using -sT:

```
stevennl@stevennl:~$ sudo nmap -sT 192.168.199.201
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-31 19:43 CST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.199.201
Host is up (0.00058s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
MAC Address: 08:00:27:9E:4C:49 (Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.47 seconds
```

Using -sS:

```
stevennl@stevennl:~$ sudo nmap -sS 192.168.199.201
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-31 19:43 CST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.199.201
Host is up (0.00040s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
MAC Address: 08:00:27:9E:4C:49 (Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.81 seconds
```

I am wondering why it takes more time to scan when using -sS parameter. Because using -sT needs to finish TCP’s three times handshake but using -sS will not establish a TCP connection. So using -sS must be faster, but the result is opposite, am I wrong?

Comment: This sounds like a question to post in either [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) as it does not seem to have much to do with programming which is [the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of external factors that could come into play. Here are a few ideas:

- Oracle VirtualBox may be doing some sort of packet translation or other abstraction that works faster with normal socket calls instead of raw sockets that Nmap uses for `-sS`.
- The reverse-DNS lookup failed in both cases, so maybe it failed faster in one case vs the other. Use `-n` to skip this step.
- Something else might have been using more network bandwidth during the `-sS` scan. Nmap is generally well-behaved and will back off and retry if packets are dropped due to link saturation.
- You may have the unlucky combination of libpcap 1.5 and later with Linux 3.19 or earlier that results in packet loss and slow scanning, though I'd expect even more slowdown than this if that were the case.

There are many other possible explanations. The times are really quite close together.